# Why does launching spark-shell with yarn-client fail with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream"?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to set up a cluster at home for my personal needs (learning). First I made Hadoop+Yarn. MR2 is working. Second - I am trying to add Spark but getting an error about missing classes.

```
[root@master conf]# spark-shell --master yarn-client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
```

I followed these [instructions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html) and added into `spark-env.sh`

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop)
```

**More info**:
Cent_OS.86_64
Hadoop dir: `/usr/local/hadoop`

Hadoop version:

```
[root@master conf]# hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 15ecc87ccf4a0228f35af08fc56de536e6ce657
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-06-29T06:04Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum fc0a1a23fc1868e4d5ee7fa2b28a58a
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
```

[Manual](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) says that I must have 2 vars: `HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR`

```
[root@master conf]# echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
[root@master conf]# echo $YARN_CONF_DIR
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
```

Spark is `spark-1.5.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz` -> `/usr/local/spark`

I am trying to launch `spark-shell --master yarn-client` at the same time when hadoop+yarn are up and available `http://master:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` `http://master:8088/cluster/apps` `http://master:19888/jobhistory`

I have no Scala installed if it matters. 
Any ideas what could I miss in Spark settings? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:
First of all this is my personal mistake.
Calling `spark-shell` I was launching it from the old (wrong) place `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/bin/spark-shell`. I was sure that I've deleted all from CDH testings by `yum remove cloudera*`.

```
[root@master bin]# type spark-shell
spark-shell is hashed (/usr/bin/spark-shell)
[root@master bin]# hash -d spark-shell
```

Now, launching if from old `spark-1.5.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz` still gave me the same error. Downloaded `spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6`, added `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME` - spark-shell is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because by typing `spark-shell`, `/usr/bin/spark-shell` was getting executed.

To call my specific spark-shell, I ran the following command from inside of own-built spark source -

```
./bin/spark-shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `spark-1.5.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz` download one of the builds for Hadoop 2.x. They are simpler to set up as they come with the Hadoop client libraries.

Comment: The Hadoop client and server versions don't have to match. Any 2.x client library is fine with a 2.x system as far as I've seen. I can't think of how you could get the same error with that build, since it certainly contains that class. If you just run `spark-shell` without parameters does it work? Can you access HDFS from it? Since it's not a YARN error it will be easier to debug with a `local` master instead of `yarn-client`.